# How to store a complex expression in a java string variable?

Tags: java

I have a expression `To="+911234567899"&From="+9987654321"&Body="Hen"` which I need to store in a java string variable. How can I do this? When I trying to put escape characters around double quotes (\") the expression still doesn't recognized as a valid string.

Comment: `String input = "To=\"+911234567899\"&From=\"+9987654321\"&Body=\"Hen\"";`

Comment: If you are coming from `Python`, there are no raw strings here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need to store all of it in a single string? I suggest splitting it on & and store it in 3 different strings. You can use `"To=\"+911234567899\"&From=\"+9987654321\"&Body=\"Hen\"".Split('&');` and retrieve the values from 0th, 1st and 2nd index.

If you still have a need to put it inside a single string, you can use string `"To=\"+911234567899\"&From=\"+9987654321\"&Body=\"Hen\""` and for future, learn character escaping in Java. This tool can help: https://codebeautify.org/java-escape-unescape

Comment: I have to perform encoding on the entire string hence I need to store all this in a single string. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape it properly:

```
String str = "To=\"+911234567899\"&From=\"+9987654321\"&Body=\"Hen\"";
System.out.println(str);
```

Output:

```
To="+911234567899"&From="+9987654321"&Body="Hen"
```